# Do i need to be on a 2nd Cycle to unlock Asagi in Disgaea D2

Tags: disgaea-d2

i got the guide book yesterday and i flipped though it looking to see if i could find Asagi to check if she was already in the game and what level she would be if i fight her or if i may have to wait for her as DLC

the guide talks about getting her post game as a "detour" as a bill is available after chapter 5 to unlock her stages, however i wanted to avoid too many spoilers by reading the guide so i'm not sure if the guide has you complete a different ending early on to get into the 2nd cycle

so i am wondering, in Disgaea D2, do i need to be on a 2nd cycle in order to get the bill to unlock Asagi's stages or can i get her in my first cycle

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to wait until the second cycle to unlock Asagi. Just follow the steps to complete her side-quest, and she's yours to keep.

Sources:

- http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/687861-disgaea-d2-a-brighter-darkness/67316514
- http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/687861-disgaea-d2-a-brighter-darkness/faqs/68086 (WARNING: Contains spoilers for other secret characters.)